Who were these Nazi bishops?
Who were the Nazi bishops shown at 00:23 and 00:32 in this video?



Very deceptive photo on top. At first glance it appears that the clerics are doing the Nazi salute. A simple reverse image search gives an indication that one of them is Ludwig Müller, Reichsbischof

@justCal He is shaking Hitler's hand…

@justCal So a Lutheran?

According to the linked Wikipedia article he started out that way. It appears Hitler was trying to define his own state church later: the Nazi regime's plan was to "coordinate" all 28 separate Protestant regional church bodies into a single and unitary Reichskirche ("Church of the Reich")

@justCal - What I know about the proposed "Church of the Reich" was ... wild. They basically decided stock Christianity was so inconsistent with their values (like that's not a huge hint?) that they were going to have to ditch the entire Old Testament and write themselves a brand new fifth (racist) gospel.

@T.E.D. If that is true, then I would say that history is repeating itself (in certain places) without those concerned learning from the mistakes of the past.

@MarkJohnson - That's honestly part of why I find that so remarkable. People like the Westboro Baptists manage to be quite bigoted and hateful without benefit of explicit Bible editing. If you're so off that you need that editing...

Maybe more than just a couple of such bishops, judging from this post. The New York Times article dated Dec. 7th 1941 said: The conference of German Catholic Bishops assembled in Fulda has recommended the introduction of a special "war prayer" which is
to be read at the beginning and end of all divine services...The Bishops further instructed Catholic clergy to keep and remember in a special Sunday sermon at least once a month German soldiers "on land, on sea and in the air."

The picture on top I found at the Holocaust Encyclopedia.
The man to the left is Albanus Schachleiter, a Benedictine who got comfortable with Hitler pretty early, and was actually suspended for that.
The man to the right is Ludwig Müller, a Lutheran and leading member of the German Christians, a movement that "aligned towards the antisemitic, racist, and Führerprinzip ideological principles of Nazism with the goal to align German Protestantism as a whole towards those principles."
The picture on the bottom I found on Traces of Evil.
The man at the left border is Franz Rudolf Bornewasser, Roman Catholic bishop of Trier.
The man to the right of him is Ludwig Sebastian, Roman Catholic bishop of Speyer.
Both of these are said to have remained carefully critical of the Nazi regime.
